# How to calculate cumulative sums of ones with a reset each time a zero is encountered

Tags: arrays, numpy, reset, cumulative-sum

I have an array made of 0 and 1. I want to calculate a cumulative sum of all consecutive 1 with a reset each time a 0 is met, using numpy as I have thousands of arrays of thousands of lines and columns.

I can do it with loops but I suspect it will not be **efficient**.
Would you have a smarter and quick way to run it on the array.
Here is short example of the input and the expected output:

```
import numpy as np
arr_in = np.array([[1,1,1,1,1,1], [0,0,0,0,0,0], [1,0,1,0,1,1], [0,1,1,1,0,0]])
print(arr_in)
print("expected result:")
arr_out = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6], [0,0,0,0,0,0], [1,0,1,0,1,2], [0,1,2,3,0,0]])
print(arr_out)
```

When you run it:

```
[[1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 1 0 1 1]
 [0 1 1 1 0 0]]
expected result:
[[1 2 3 4 5 6]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 1 0 1 2]
 [0 1 2 3 0 0]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [`numba.vectorize`](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/vectorize.html) you can define a custom `numpy` ufunc to use for accumulation.

```py
import numba as nb # v0.56.4, no support for numpy >= 1.22.0
import numpy as np # v1.21.6

@nb.vectorize([nb.int64(nb.int64, nb.int64)])
def reset_cumsum(x, y):
    return x + y if y else 0

arr_in = np.array([[1,1,1,1,1,1],
                   [0,0,0,0,0,0],
                   [1,0,1,0,1,1],
                   [0,1,1,1,0,0]])

reset_cumsum.accumulate(arr_in, axis=1)
```

Output

```
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: Are you sure of the function definition? how can `axis=1` be evaluated? I also get a "*TypeError: accumulate() takes from 1 to 4 positional arguments but 140332626758656 were given*"

Comment: @mozway - Yes, I tested the solution with `numba 0.56.4` and `numpy 1.21.6`. Unfortunately `numba` doesn't work with newer `numpy` versions. [Working colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1oXr-QAmaKtO5e5J8k80lNdCzaAQvYFeS?usp=sharing)

Comment: I had tested on numpy 1.23.5 / numba 0.53.1. Thanks for the feedback, it's always nice to read your answers/comments!

Comment: Great, both solutions work with a large array (although I did not check my np and nb versions).
Solution with numba is 3x faster.
Thank you very much, gentlemen

Answer (score 2):

You can compute the [`cumsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.cumsum.html) for the 1s, then identify the 0s and forward-fill the cumulated sum to subtract it:

```
# identify 0s
mask = arr_in==0

# get classical cumsum
cs = arr_in.cumsum(axis=1)

# ffill the cumsum value on 1s
# subtract from cumsum
out = cs-np.maximum.accumulate(np.where(mask, cs, 0), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
[[1 2 3 4 5 6]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 1 0 1 2]
 [0 1 2 3 0 0]]
```

Output on second example:

```
[[1 2 3 4 5 6 0 1]
 [0 1 2 0 0 0 1 0]]
```

Comment: Wonderful, @mozway. I understood your explanations, but not really your code. But as it works, I'm delighted...

Comment: @tibibou take the time to break it into individual parts and let me know if you have any question ;)

Comment: After further investigations (while trying to understand), I found a mistake using the following simple array:

arr_in = np.array([[1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1], [0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0]])

Comment: @tibibou you're right, I used a different approach, which is also more simple